# Cannot find the highest and lowest

Tags: java

I have some problems in highest and lowest.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab3bq1 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double [] num = new double[10];
    double [] p = new double[10];
    System.out.println("Enter the number of books purchased by :");
    for(int i=0;i<num.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.print("Customer #"+(i+1)+ " = ");
        num[i] = input.nextDouble();
    }
    System.out.println("Review for 10 Selected Customers");
    System.out.println("Points Awarded:");
    setp(num,p);
    System.out.println("Total books purchased : "+settotalbook(num));
    System.out.println("Highest points : Customer "+sethighest(p));
    System.out.println("Lowest points : Customer "+setlowest(p));
}

public static void setp(double[] num, double[] p)
{
    for(int i=0;i<p.length;i++)
    {
        if(num[i]>=1 && num[i]<=3)
           p[i] = 10;
        else if(num[i]<=6)
            p[i] = 25;
        else if(num[i]<=9)
            p[i] = 40;
        else 
            p[i] = 75;
        System.out.println("Customer #"+(i+1)+ " = " + p[i] + " points");
    }
}
public static double settotalbook(double[] num)
{
    double total=0;
    for(int i=0;i<num.length;i++)
    {
        total+=num[i];
    }
    return total;
}
public static double sethighest(double[] p)
{
    double max=p[0], custnum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<p.length;i++)
    {
        if(p[i]>max)
            max=p[i];
        custnum=i;
    }
    return (custnum+1);
}
public static double setlowest(double[] p)
{
    double min=p[0], custnum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<p.length;i++)
    {
        if(p[i]<min)
            min=p[i];
        custnum=i;
    }
    return (custnum+1);
 }
 }
```

Comment: you should return max in the sethighest method and min in the setlowest method ...

Comment: I know but my question ask me to return which customer has the maximum value.

Comment: Use BubbleSort or any, once you have sorted then take first and last element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with if block in both method

try:

```
 if(p[i]<min){
            min=p[i];
            custnum=i;
     }
```

and

```
  if(p[i]>max){
            max=p[i];
            custnum=i;
       }
```

store customer number who have min or max value..

Comment: If this was the solution of your problem please mark it as accepted answer so others don't waste their time to analyzing the same issue :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are beginner. Anyway, you should return max in the sethighest method and min in the setlowest method as @Uta Alexandru suggested.

There is one more mistake in the code. Whenever we write something like

```
if(condition)
statement#1
statement#2
```

So if condition is true then only statement#1 will execute and statement#2 is out of the condition.

Here in your code your wrote

```
 if(p[i]>max)
        max=p[i];
    custnum=i;
```

and

```
 if(p[i]<min)
        min=p[i];
    custnum=i;
```

**custnum** is updated at every iteration in loop.

If you want it to be updated only when your condition is true then you need to put your code in block like this.

```
if(p[i]>max) {
    max=p[i];
    custnum=i;
}
```

and

```
if(p[i]<min) {
    min=p[i];
    custnum=i;
}
```

Hope this helps. Enjoy :)